# My empty but not empty fish tank

Tags: aquarium, fish, goldfish

My Betta died a couple weeks ago so now i have a tank filled with water, can my small female goldfish be in the small rectangular container that has rocks a cave and a sea anemone, and this tank has no pump or heater but my room is room temperature, the fish tank does have a floor filter so will i be able to keep a small goldfish in there without it dying for a while.

Comment: How many litres is the fish tank? If you're not sure you can measure it and use a [volume calculator](https://www.calculator.net/volume-calculator.html). Also, you say this tank has no pump but does have a floor filter, normally an under-gravel filter would have a pump attached. Could you clarify or post a picture?

Comment: where is your goldfish now,something tells me that it have a lot more water to swim in now than it will have in your betta tank.i do not want this to sound rude but goldfish need a lot of water and they do make a lot of waste compared to other types of fish.